# Resize image directly from Rackspace Cloud Files 'object' without downloading?

Tags: php, rackspace-cloud

I have moved my images to Rackspace Cloud Files and am using their PHP API. I am trying to do the following:

1. Get an image from my "originals" container
2. Resize it, sharpen it, etc.
3. Save the resized image to the "thumbs" container

My problem is with #2. I was hoping to resize without having to copy the original to my server first (since the images are large and I'd like to resize dynamically), but can't figure out how. This is what I have so far (not much):

```
$container = $conn->get_container("originals"); 
$obj = $container->get_object("example.jpg"); 
$img = $obj->read();
```

Part of the problem is I don't fully understand what is being returned by the read() function. I know $img contains the object's "data" (which I was able to print out as gibberish), but it is neither a file nor a url nor an image resource, so I don't know how to deal with it. Is it possible to convert $img into an image resource somehow?  I tried imagecreatefromjpeg($img) but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try outputting the $img into a file i.e. modifiedImage.jpg ? use fopen() to open a file with write permission, dump the content of the variable $img in it, and close the handle. See if it works... As a sanity check I would look at the first few characters of the gibberish in the $img variable to see what type of data is contained in it.

Comment: What's this `read` function? I can't see where that's coming from.

Comment: @Link That seems like a great idea - would you be willing to provide some quick sample code? I'm not very familiar with fopen() so not sure exactly how to do it, especially the dumping-the-content part.

Comment: @deceze It's from the PHP API provided by Rackspace (https://github.com/rackspace/php-cloudfiles). Specifically, it's defined in cloudfiles.php.

Comment: Also: (1) The first few characters of the file are "ÿØÿàJFIFHHÿá ÁExifII*Á¶ w‰‘(1™2µ;É˜‚Õ¥ÄÐéi‡¼ÐIvy-covered south facade". (2) I had mistyped the read() part in my post and have corrected it above. Sorry about that!

Comment: Yes ÿØÿà is in the header of most JPEG files, which can mean that this is a .jpg file. It's the file's signature.[http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000018.shtml](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000018.shtml)

Comment: I did not know that! Interesting. Thanks for all your help, Link - I understand how files work a lot better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you cannot resize an image without loading it into memory. Unless the remote server offers some *"resize my image for me, here are the parameters"* API, you have to load the image in your script to manipulate it. So you'll have to copy the file from the CloudFiles container to your server, manipulate it, then send it back into storage.

The data you receive from `$obj->read()` is the image data. That is *the file*. It doesn't have a *file name* and it's not saved on the hard disk, but it is the entire file. To load this into `gd` to manipulate it, you can use [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php). That's analogous to using, for example, `imagecreatefrompng`, only that `imagecreatefrompng` wants to read a *file* from the file system by itself, while `imagecreatefromstring` just accepts the data that you have already loaded into memory.

Comment: imagecreatefromstring! I didn't know about that function, thanks! That is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. I tried it and it worked great. I'll have to test to see if it's faster than the other methods, but it seems like it should be, since it skips a step (copying from cloud to server, _then_ applying imagecreatefromjpg).

Comment: @Holly You still need to copy the data from the cloud to your server, you just don't need to write it to a file on the hard disk.

Comment: @deceze : can you please provide code of resizing and again write that re-size image to cloud server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to dump the content of the $img variable into a writable file as per the below:

```
<?php
$filename = 'modifiedImage.jpg';

/* 
 * 'w+' Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate 
 * the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. 
 */
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');

// Write $img to the opened\created file.
if (fwrite($handle, $img) === FALSE) {
    echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
    exit;
}

echo "Success, wrote to file ($filename)";

fclose($handle);
?>
```

**More details:**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

***Edit:***

You might also want to double check the type of data returned by the read() function, because if the data is not a jpg image, if it's for example a png, the extension of the file needs to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Or you can also use the `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()` functions which perform the same general purpose as the above.

Comment: Thanks so much for the code. It worked! But isn't that basically the same as copying the file to my server? (The API has a function for that: save_to_filename()). Or is this method faster/better somehow? I was hoping to avoid copying altogether and work with the image in memory. But I realize this may be impossible, which I can live with.

Comment: I do not assume that this method is by any means faster\better than the API's save_to_filename() method, however the pros of this method is that you have more control over what you save. Digg in a bit further with regard to the save_to_filename() method and experiment a bit with it. You might find that it was what you were looking for all along :)

Comment: Thanks Link. I did some digging around and did find some interesting things: (1) the save_to_filename() method uses the stream() method rather than read(). (2) The stream method includes this example:                  `header("Content-Type: " . $obj->content_type);
     $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
     $obj->stream($output); 
     fclose($output);` - could this be what I'm looking for? I thought this was only to display to browser, but maybe...